# Simplest way to save data when Serialization is no option

Tags: java, serialization, save, persistence

I am working on a game. It has a `Game` class where everything is created and other objects are stored, a `Player` class with an Inventory of `Item`s, and then there are `Room`s where the Player can go and in these rooms we have other Items and `Enemy`s and so on. Its a fairly simple programm.

I have to implement an Option to save and load the current game state. I tried using the `Serializable` interface, but I encountered the problem that all of my Item classes store `StringPropertys`. Saving those objects obviously doesnt work scince StringProperty doesnt implement the interface.

Then I thought about writing everything in a simple text file. But loading that will be pretty elaborate.

Persisting the data with an Database would be an asolute overkill for that project. I also know there are other possibilities like XML, but I have never done that before.

What I basically want is the easiest (does not have to be the prettiest/cleanest) option to save my game state, so when someone wants to load the game, I can simply create a new `Game` and `Player` and just do something like `newPlayer.setCurrentLocation(savedLocation)` and so on.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is "too opinionated" (in my opinion). There are various ways to do that; and no really "best" solution stands out. I think the "most natural" thing to do: read about the JSON format; learn about the existing libraries that help with creating/reading JSON data ... and start trying.

Comment: [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) is what you want.  It’s literally designed to serialize objects based on their properties.  I assume for every StringProperty, you have a get-method and a set-method, just like all the JavaFX classes do.

Comment: That looks promising. However, I think that needs too much refactoring for me at the moment. But I will keep that in mind